# Any tips on how to get nord piano 3 to sound better?

Tags: piano, recording, keyboard, homerecording, audition

1

2 http://www.mediafire.com/file/l7oqhcb2yl2hbsb/2018-07-28_13-01-14.mp3/file

using two ts cable, effects are turned off and it is raw non-edited recording.

first one was recorded using obs to record video plus audio while the second one was recorded in audition (I don't know why there is so much reverb in the audition recording

both audio are recorded in 320kbps and in stereo

I'm looking to get this kind of sound

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with your cables. You need to find a brighter sounding piano patch than the miserable thing you used in your two demos. Also, you need to teach your left hand to play more softly - and in fact your touch is pretty uneven for both hands, which results in random notes "sticking out as too loud" for no musical reason.

Comment: the thing is I don't know which sample is best for recording

Comment: Just keep trying  different ones till you find one that sounds like the guy you want to imitate! Real pianos don't all sound the same. Anybody familiar with them can easily recognize the sound of a Yamaha, Steinway, Bosendorfer, etc, etc by ear - they are as different as chalk and cheese. (And actually, no two concert grands made by the *same* company have ever sounded *exactly* alike - professionals might try 20 or 30 pianos of the same brand before  they decide which one they like "best".

Comment: Hey so I noticed something. so my speakers creative gigaworks t20 series II) and guitar amp (both under 100) sound pretty bad. worse than my headphone at least. I was doing some recording in obs and audacity so far audacity sounds best so I have to figure out how to edit. the headphone sounded way better in the recordings and when I switch to the speakers (creative) it clips so much even when I'm not playing loudly.

Comment: how does it sound on your end? you prolly have much better speakers and headphones than i have

Answer (score 2):

There is no best sample for recording, you are just using a different sample from the one used in the video you want to emulate. Check here:

http://www.nordkeyboards.com/sound-libraries/nord-piano-library/grand-pianos/royal-grand-3d

Listen to the sound demos. When you find the one you want, make sure you download the version with "XL" in the file name - that will have the highest quality. Use the Nord sample management software and a USB cable to load the sample into your piano - unless you already have it. If you already have, just select it.

You might have to read the manuals that came with the Nord (also available on their web site) to learn to select and/or download the sample that sounds like the sound you want.